# Windows gets locked when using a WIN key combo

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey,
but I follow the instructions & examples from other users

recently I've stumbled into a problem that I haven't seen reported,

I have assigned WIN+z key to start a program & after every few times using it, it locks my session,

when I change to CTRL+z it never happens.

any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: Post code so maybe someone can see if there's something wrong. And looking at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) page, WIN+Z seems to "Show the commands available in an app in full-screen mode."

Comment: What script are you using? What program are you trying to start? What do you mean by "locks"? Existing windows keybinds should not influence the behaviour of the script.

Comment: I'm triggering a bat file, but windows locks before triggering like if I would press win+L key